# Why is there no edit in Blend option in WPF4?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, wpf-4.0

I am a Silverlight 4 developer getting started with WPF4. In Silverlight 4, there is option available in menu "Edit in Blend" when you right click on any xaml file. Why is this option not available in WPF4?

Do I need to download some patch for Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: You can use my `OpenInExpressionBlend` macro described in this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539758/wpf-blend-visual-studio-regedit/4544470#4544470

Answer (score 0):

you can add one yourself to the tools menu

Tools->External Tools...->Add

then fill out the path etc. and **bam** you have your "Edit In Blend" command.

kinda sucks, one would think that the install for VS2k10 and the install for Blend would do this for you... Check to see if the other is installed, maybe give you an option to add the command, then install the command for you.  Blend has a command for editing in VS built in, so why not the other way around?